# Eval in the context of another class

Tags: ruby

I have the following code

```
class Tester

  def eval_something(string)
    eval(string)  # How to change?
  end

  def printer
    p "Not what I want"
  end
end

class MyClass

  def printer
    p "Hello World"
  end
end

t = Tester.new
t.eval_something("printer")
```

I want a `Tester` instance's `eval_something`  to evaluate the code in the context of `MyClass`. So for example, I want this script to print out `Hello World` instead of `Not what I want`.

Can this be achieved?

Comment: You don't want MyClass as subclass of Tester.. right ? Or any suggestions you are ready to agree to change the code of yours ?

Comment: Yes, `MyClass` is a separate entity that has nothing to do with `Tester`. Basically I want to know whether I can have one class do an eval using the context of another class.

Comment: Your question doesn't make sense. `printer` is an instance method. It **can't** be evaluated in the context of `MyClass` - it can only be evaluated in the context of an _instance_ of `MyClass`. There are a variety of potential solutions to your problem, but they all involve a fundamental change in how your code is structured and it isn't clear to me what you actually want.

It sounds like you want to call an instance method from another class without creating an instance of that class, but that makes no sense.

Answer (score 0):

Not quite sure if this would work for your purposes, but you can try this:

```
class Tester
  def eval_something(string)
    MyClass.send(string.to_sym)  # Send will evaluate the symbol passed to it.  Equivalent of calling MyClass.printer in this case
  end

  def printer
    p "Not what I want"
  end
end

class MyClass
  def self.printer   # This needs to be a class method since MyClass does not inherit from Tester in this example
    p "Hello World"
  end
end

t = Tester.new
t.eval_something("printer")

=> "Hello World"
```

Comment: I guess I could instantiate an instance of `MyClass` as @tlewin suggests and send that to it. On the other hand, if I'm going to be instantiating one anyways, I could instantiate it once, store it as a class variable, and then just use that instead.

Answer (score 0):

In your example, you can use the `instance_eval` method and pass a `MyClass` reference:

```
t = Tester.new
t.instance_eval do
  MyClass.new.printer
end
```

This will return "Hello World".

The [`instance_eval`](http://rubydoc.info/stdlib/core/BasicObject%3ainstance_eval) runs the code block that you pass in the context of the object. In this case you can access any instance variable. For example:

```
class Test
  def initialize any
    @any = any
  end
end

t = Test.new('abc')
t.instance_eval {puts @any}
```

It will print 'abc'.

It is recommendable to use the `instance_eval` and `class_eval` methods, since it gives to you more control to what it will execute. It is a safer option.

The `eval` method can execute an arbitrary code. If you do not control the content of string, it will be very risk option.

Comment: Your use of `instance_eval` is completely tangential to the question. Using it on an instance of `Tester` doesn't make it any easier to call `MyClass`'s instance method.

Comment: @Max you are totally correct. That's the reason I included `MyClass.new` inside the `instance_eval` code block.